# Workspace field not gettting in Graph API search

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I am creating an event in sharepoint and using graph API search, I am searcing events with title and getting response. But there is workspace field in event list (which keep the event link address and display name). But unfortunately I am not getting these fields in Sharepoint response. I tried to give "WorkspaceOWSURLH" similar to "BannerUrlOWSURLH". But I am getting the field BannerUrl in response, but not the Workspace field.

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/search/query' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer mytoken' \
--data-raw '{
    "requests": [
    {    
      "entityTypes": [
      "listItem"
      ],
      "query": {
        "queryString": Path:https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteName/ AND contentType=Event AND Title:Test"
      },
     "from": 0,
      "size": 25,
      "fields": [
        "title","description" , "LocationOWSTEXT","EventDateOWSDATE", "EndDateOWSDATE" ,"BannerUrlOWSURLH",**"WorkspaceOWSURLH"**  //this field not getting in response. Rest all I am getting*
      ]
    }] 

}'
```

Comment: Have you checked if the WorkspaceOWSURLH field is listed as a crawled or managed property in the Search schema of the SharePoint Online Admin centre? Btw, I don't see it listed in the search schema of my dev environment.

Comment: I think the property "workspace" is not defined in the events as seen in document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/calendar?view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: @Expiscornovus --> its not there in both crawled and managed property